# <a href="#example">Example Link</a> with padding or margin?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site with a Sticky Navigation and when I use

`<a href="#example">Example Link</a>`

the Sticky Nav overlaps the top of the `#example`.

The Nav height is `70px` so I'm wondering if there's any way to link to `#example` but start 70px down. I'd rather not create an additional ID since it will probably make things a mess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
window.scrollBy(0,70);
```

to scroll the window 70px down.

To have it actually scroll after linking, you have to change your link such that it executes a javascript relocation before scrolling: `window.location='#example'; window.scrollBy(0,70);`

Answer (score 0):

That is the job of `#example`. It moves you to the location of the element with that id.

You can use jQuery to animate your elements to slideUp or your window to scrollTo 70px down.